Next Js middleware & API cant call third party api
I have this following route which exists src/app/test/page.tsx
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

async function getRandom() {
  try {
    const response = axios.get(
      "http://api.localhost/api-admin/auth/random"
    );
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
const page = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getRandom().then((response) => {
      console.log(response); //gets data
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>test</div>;
};

export default page;

When i do this i get back data in the client side.
However when I do it in server.side (middleware and api) , i keep getting cors origin error
src/Middleware.ts
import { NextResponse, NextFetchEvent } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import axios from "axios";

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "http://api.localhost/api-admin/api/auth/random"
    );
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  const result = await getData();
  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
};

In src/app/api/test/route.ts
import axios from "axios";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "http://api.localhost/api-admin/auth/random"
    );
    return Response.json({ message: "hello", data: res.data });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }

I am not sure if I need to set up the cors header or modify the next.config.js .
